# What is the best way to handle node_modules in a microservice architecture project using serverless framework on AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

**Here I am using this architecture, please suggest me a better one, I am new in this field.**

**Project structure**

```
|models
|node_modules
|package.json
|services
    |serviceA
    |      |---handler.js
    |      |---serverless.yml
    |serviceB
    |     |---get.js
          |---delete.js
          |---serverless.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have `package.json` (and `node_modules`) inside each service directory - it is needed because otherwise the `node_modules` directory will not be deployed.